# Regex pattern for Eventlog 4740 with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Given is a logfile called **sample_log.txt** which contains sample data of the windows security eventlog. I want to search with a regex pattern for locked out user accounts which is **Event ID 4740**.

Such a sample looks like this:

```
Information 22.12.2020 21:28:46 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4740    User Account Management "A user account was locked out.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SERVER23$
    Account Domain:     DOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Account That Was Locked Out:
    Security ID:        domain\firstname.lastname
    Account Name:       firstname.lastname
```

I've the following powershell script:

```
#grab our data
$file = get-content "$PSScriptRoot\sample_log.txt"

#make our pattern

$regex = "Account Name:\s*(\w+).(\w+)"
#loop through each lin
foreach ($line in $file)
{
#if our line contains our pattern, write the matched data to the screen
if($line -match $regex)
{
$matches[0]
}
}
```

Actually the output would look like this:

```
 Account Name:      SERVER23
 Account Name:      firstname.lastname
```

How can I expand/modify the regex pattern if I want only match events with **ID 4740** that contains the **date and time stamp** together with the **account name** from the sample above?

Thanks in advance for every help and suggestion

Comment: If the structure is the same, you might use a pattern to check for the presence of the lines  and use 2 capturing groups `^.*?\bMicrosoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4740 .*(?:\r?\n(?!Subject:).*)*\r?\nSubject:(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*(\w+)\$(?:\r?\n(?!Account).*)*\r?\nAccount.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\rn]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)`  https://regex101.com/r/F71XVL/1

Comment: If you can go back to the original log, there's a builtin way to get the xml version of the log then access the fields you want.

Comment: Why not using the [`Get-EventLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog) cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of the data is the same, one option is to use a specific pattern checking all lines for the expected values making use of a negative lookahead.

Use `-Raw` to get the contents of a file as one string.

Capture the value of the account name's in capture group 1 and 2.

```
^Information \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} .*? 4740 .*(?:\r?\n(?!Subject:).*)*\r?\nSubject:(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*\b(Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*\w+)\$(?:\r?\n(?!Account).*)*\r?\nAccount.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\rn]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*\b(Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*\S+)
```

The pattern matches

- `^Information \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} .*? 4740 .*` Match the first line with a "date like" pattern and the number 4740
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Subject:).*)*\r?\n` Match the following lines that do not start with `Subject:`
- `Subject:(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n` Match `Subject:` followed by matching all lines that do not start with Account name:
- `.*\b(Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*\w+)\$` Capture in **group 1** matching `Account Name:` followed by the spaces and 1+ word chars for the name itself
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Account).*)*\r?\nAccount.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\rn]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*\b` The same approach for the second part first matching Account, then till Account Name:
- `(Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*\S+)` Capture in **group 2** matching `Account Name:` the spaces the account name part itself (using `\S+` assuming it can not contain spaces)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bp48ks/1) and a [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##nVJda9swFH33r7grhsQuFoka1mEoriHZCNQN1P1gVG1RbSVRZ0tBlkhHl9@eOf7Ayej6UL1InHPu0blXWsk1U8WSZdl2a895xs7Oe9ZUzKXKqeZSAMZoiBEe4AHgoY@/@aOvEPFEyULOtXfHRSrXhRezxCiuf3uhSbnmYgGj09EAynVTMAVhkkgjNERU0AXLWXk8CsHsKNpQa1pAJpNfLAVpNLKs2Dy/sET71s6l9Yfp2IdmxT/j60lU0a3/Jc1Zy8eTq9vJFT6xDxRjmVMuas14FoXTy4q@kIuy18588HoyObWstup6STXclQkv6oQz80GutLqCzLkqtCgDoYzWh/9GfUfaO7csW7EFe4Uz6PWD3HncfxWSvuENQd022gByg3rqyO0HPlEBEf3gSztGB7mOW4Etsie6fyQxUUQ8uAfxuhrkkuf@AdeVkPWxQ@w9t0bXVTfAQa66/pM3xsdOz4pZVrbhxVrt/lszLI@LldFQfWXwwiyLqE6WrIA/8F0qRpOlN6vahzf7CTXk5h22eqxS8kNJsyruhw/olmaG/QPjFt5st38B)

**Example code**

```
$file = Get-Content -Raw sample_log.txt

$regex = '(?m)^Information \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} .*? 4740 .*(?:\r?\n(?!Subject:).*)*\r?\nSubject:(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*\b(Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*\w+)\$(?:\r?\n(?!Account).*)*\r?\nAccount.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\rn]*Account Name:).*)*\r?\n.*\b(Account Name:[^\S\r\n]*\S+)'
Select-String $regex -input $file -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
    $_.Groups[2].Value
}
```

**Output**

```
Account Name:       SERVER23
Account Name:       firstname.lastname
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and good answer! :) It worked like a charm. I had only one small problem. The exported txt log comes preformatted with "tabs" that look like "spaces" and therefore the regex pattern didn't match. See [link](https://regex101.com/r/4yuoAD/1) Maybe for the future xml is a better way to go

Comment: @FreeRunner I see, you can change the spaces around the number as well. See https://regex101.com/r/DPG5BE/1

Comment: Cool, never learned out :) Thanks for that!